# MathJax word wrap

Tags: html, ios, css, mathjax

I have configured extra processing for MathJax with this code below

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">

    MathJax.Hub.Config({
    tex2jax: { inlineMath: [["$","$"],["\\(","\\)"]] },
    "HTML-CSS": {
       linebreaks: { width: "container" }          
    }              
    });

</script>
```

As I assumed it has to work with word wrap containers that I have in my HTML code.

I have this CSS that set with word-wrap

```
.col {
        background: #f0f0f0; 
        width: 230px; 
        padding: 10px; 
        font-size: 1.5em; 
        word-wrap: break-word; 
    }
```

this is my body:

```
<body>

        <div class = 'col'>

        $$
           Pr [( G \bigcup B \bigcup S)^e ] = 1 - Pr ( G \bigcup B \bigcup S)                
           = 1 - [Pr(G)+Pr(B)Pr(S)-Pr(G \bigcap B) - Pr(G \bigcap S) - Pr(B \bigcap S)]
           Pr [( G \bigcup B \bigcup S)^e ] = 1 - Pr ( G \bigcup B \bigcup S)
           = 1 - [Pr(G)+Pr(B)Pr(S)-Pr(G \bigcap B) - Pr(G \bigcap S) - Pr(B \bigcap S)]
           = 1 - (0.28 + 0.29 + 0.19 - 0.14 - 0.10 -0.12 + 0.08) = 1 - 0.48 = 0.52
        $$

        </div>

</body>
```

but word wrap does not work in my case.

I've attached screenshot how it looks in Safri on iPad

[image]

the words must wrap to the second line but they don't ad you can see.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EDIT
If you're on iOS6, then you might run into [this MathJax bug](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/368).

MathJax uses its own line-breaking algorithm ([implementing the MathML specs](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/whats-new-2.0.html?highlight=linebreaking#automatic-line-breaking-of-long-displayed-equations)). Setting `word-wrap: break-word;` will not change its behavior.

Unless there's some information missing, you code works as expected for me, i.e., MathJax does its linebreaking.

Here's a complete example.

```
<!doctype HTML>
<head>
<title>Break!</title>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">

MathJax.Hub.Config({
tex2jax: { inlineMath: [["$","$"],["\\(","\\)"]] },
"HTML-CSS": {
  linebreaks: { automatic: true, width: "container" }          
}              
});

</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
<style>
.col {
    background: #f0f0f0; 
    width: 230px; 
    padding: 10px; 
    font-size: 1.5em; 
    word-wrap: break-word; 
}  
</style>

</head>
<body>

    <div class = 'col'>

    $$
      Pr [( G \bigcup B \bigcup S)^e ] = 1 - Pr ( G \bigcup B \bigcup S)                
      = 1 - [Pr(G)+Pr(B)Pr(S)-Pr(G \bigcap B) - Pr(G \bigcap S) - Pr(B \bigcap S)]
      Pr [( G \bigcup B \bigcup S)^e ] = 1 - Pr ( G \bigcup B \bigcup S)
      = 1 - [Pr(G)+Pr(B)Pr(S)-Pr(G \bigcap B) - Pr(G \bigcap S) - Pr(B \bigcap S)]
      = 1 - (0.28 + 0.29 + 0.19 - 0.14 - 0.10 -0.12 + 0.08) = 1 - 0.48 = 0.52
    $$

    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: thanks for response, but unfortunately I don't understand which options I have to setup. Can you explain how it works. How can I set width for container that will show mathematical expressions.

Comment: Your example also breaks for me.  Are you sure that you haven't selected MathML as the renderer in the MathJax contextual menu?

Comment: The [documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/HTML-CSS.html#configure-html-css) for the HTML-CSS output (see the linebreaks section) shows that you can set the width explicitly for linebreaking, or in terms of the with of the containing element.  The latter is the default, and that seems to be working for us.  Perhaps if you give a complete HTML file, and indicate the browser and OS you are using, that would help.

Comment: I am trying to add width: "container" to MathJax.Hub.Config but it does not help me.

"HTML-CSS": {
 linebreaks: { width: "container" }
}

Comment: i have update question and add screen shot. thanks for response.

Comment: Have you put the configuration block **before** the script call?

Comment: I think it would be very helpful if Matrosov can kindly include the whole HTML content - including all meta tag, script tag, etc as then everyone will be looking at the same thing. Cheers

Comment: Try using `line breaks: {width: "230px"}` and see if that works.  There have been some weird issues with iOS6 and as I recall, linebreaking was affected.  Perhaps this is another instance of that.  Safari on Mac OSX  works as expected.

Comment: Note that `width: "container"` is the default, so there is no reason to add that, and doing so will not change anything.  That is why I asked you to try using a specific width.

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander, I have tested Peter's file on an iPad mini runnin iOS6.1.1, and it works properly form me.  Can you verify that his file fails for you?  What version of iOS are you using?  What version of MathJax?

Comment: thanks guys, thanks Peter this is very helpful answer and comments and your code work for me also for all iOS versions. I have tested it using iOS versions 4.3, 5.0, 5.1, 6.0 and it works good. I just have problem with script TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML that I have locally (not on remote server) and this is not work for me, but it is very strange because I have copied http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML script to my local folder and it should work. This script from my file invokes in any case, because I tried to add alert to this file and alert has appeared.

Comment: Why are you making a local copy of TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML?  If you want to include your own custom configuration options, then you should use the technique for [using your own configuration with the CDN](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/configuration.html#using-a-local-configuration-file-with-the-cdn).  Note in particular that the `loadComplete()` call at the bottom of the file must match the URL by which you have loaded the file, so if you have moved it to your own server you need to change that.

Comment: I want to use MathJax without internet connection, using just local MathJax files that are stored in local directory. Can I do this?

Comment: Yes, but if you are planning to load it into an iPad app, you will want to remove the components you aren't using, in order to make it smaller.  See [this article](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/wiki/Shrinking-MathJax-for-%22local%22-installation) for some details.  Also, in that case, you don't need to use a combined configuration file, since using your own custom configuration is just as fast when the network isn't involved.

Comment: thanks Davide it is very useful recommendations. I faced with a big problem - processing time. Without internet connection the time for building formula components much bigger then if I use CDN.

Comment: Then I suspect there is a problem with your setup.  The rendering time should not be longer.  I'm wondering if you have removed something that you shouldn't have, and MathJax is trying to load it and timing out (it has a 15 second timeout waiting for a file to load).  You might want to add `MathJax.Hub.Queue(function(){alert(MathJax.Message.Log())})` to your configuration and see if there are any "failed to load" error messages.

Comment: I've updated the answer since cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, cf. https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced similar kind of issue, but I could not solve using that word wrap.
The issue is caused by the MathJax's default classes and hence we need to override them so that it works according to the width of the parent:

```
.mjx-chtml {
   font-size: ${IS_MOBILE ? '100%' : '120%'} !important;
}
.mjx-table {
   white-space: pre-line !important;
}
.mjx-table .mjx-char {
   white-space: ${IS_MOBILE ? 'pre-line' : 'inherit'} !important;
}
.mjx-full-width {
   width: 0em !important;
}
```